# Windows - Use default python rather than Anaconda installation

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

my problem is before I installed Anaconda, my python with `python` and `py` commands shows the same versions. After I installed Anaconda, my `python` version is using Anaconda installation. How to prevent this, because I don't want to use Anaconda python version on my Windows.

- I already put my python PATH on the top
- When I check the PATH, there's no anaconda PATH anywhere when I done my installation

My python version will use the default python version, not the Anaconda's version

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the default opener for the .py files on your computer.
try to right-click on the .py file, select "open with" and look for python.

You can always use cmd and run the following:

```
python <path_to_file>
```

or

```
python3 <path_to_file>
```

It depended on your python version

(as long as you set your python path in windows Path)